# How do i get my cascadeOnDelete to work in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

Trying to learn Laravel, i am following a tutorial from laracast called Laravel 8 from scratch and has now reached episiode about cascades
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/53

I'm not getting any errors but if i add a comment to a post, and then delete the post then my comment stays in the database, while his is removed with the post. I tried deleting the post using laravel, but also using tableplus.
My setup is a bit diffrent from his so i'm wondering if my cascades arent working because of something in my setup.

comment migration

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Post migration

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->foreignId('category_id');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('excerpt');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
    });
```

I've also tried using `$table->foreignKey('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade)` but i cant seem to get it working.

I have also tried adding the constrain my self at the mySql database using

```
alter table
   `comments`
add
   constraint `comments_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`) on 
delete cascade
```

Do i need a specific use, or could it be my setup?
[php/database setup versions from wamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPIZF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you search for myisam and innodb, you will probably find the answer.
in myisam, foreign keys are not deleted

Comment: Thanks, the tables was in myisam, i looked up how to make laravel change it and now its working.